# Is there a function for finding the full file permissions?

Tags: go, unix, file-permissions

I need to use Go to get the file permissions of a given file (specifically the SUID bit). Here are the permissions of an example file.

```
$ touch example_file.test
$ chmod 7777 example_file.test
$ ls -ltra example_file.test
    -rwsrwsrwt 1 luke users 0 Feb 25 21:53 example_file.test

$ stat -c "%a %n" example_file.test
     7777 example_file.test
```

Here is a tiny program illustrating the issue.

```
func main() {
    info, _ := os.Stat("example_file.test")
        fmt.Println(info.Mode().String())                        // ugtrwxrwxrwx
        fmt.Println(info.Mode().Perm().String())                 // -rwxrwxrwx
        fmt.Printf("permissions: %#o\n", info.Mode().Perm())     // permissions: 0777
}
```

The Go results are inconsistent because `ugtrwxrwxrwx != 0777`.

The following quote from the documentation indicates that this might be a cross-platform compatibility issue.

> A FileMode represents a file's mode and permission bits. The bits have
>   the same definition on all systems, so that information about files
>   can be moved from one system to another portably. Not all bits apply
>   to all systems. The only required bit is ModeDir for directories.
>
> type FileMode uint32 The defined file mode bits are the most
>   significant bits of the FileMode. The nine least-significant bits are
>   the standard Unix rwxrwxrwx permissions. The values of these bits
>   should be considered part of the public API and may be used in wire
>   protocols or disk representations: they must not be changed, although
>   new bits might be added.

Is this a limitation of Go?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *inconsistent*. The `Perm` part of the mode is *defined* as the low nine bits. Strip off all but the low nine bits of `ugtrwxrwxrwx` and you're left with `rwxrwxrwx`, which is exactly what you see. If you want more bits than the low nine bits, don't strip off the other bits.

Answer (score 4):

It's worth noting that in addition to the octal representations not matching, neither do the string representations:

```
"-rwsrwsrwt" != "ugtrwxrwxrwx"`
```

This is not due to a limitation of the Go implementation, but is instead a consequence of it being implemented in a system agnostic manner.

From [the `FileMode` documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileMode) (emphasis mine):

> A FileMode represents a file's mode and permission bits. The bits have
>   the same definition on all systems, so that information about files
>   can be moved from one system to another portably. **Not all bits apply
>   to all systems.**

Because the implementation isn't meant to mimic the behavior of a specific system, the output isn't guaranteed to match the native tools in a given environment. However, all of the relevant data is there to work with.

If you wanted to mimic the output of `stat` you can just author some logic to do so.

Here's a quick example that tackles the octal representation:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func UnixPerm(m os.FileMode) (p uint32) {
    p = uint32(m.Perm())
    if m & os.ModeSetuid != 0 {
        p |= 04000
    }
    if m & os.ModeSetgid != 0 {
        p |= 02000
    }
    if m & os.ModeSticky != 0 {
        p |= 01000
    }
    return p
}

func main() {
    info, _ := os.Stat("example_file")
    fmt.Printf("FileMode.Perm(): %04o\n", info.Mode().Perm())
    fmt.Printf("UnixPerm(): %04o\n", UnixPerm(info.Mode()))
}
```

Output:

```
$ go run fileperm.go
FileMode.Perm(): 0777
UnixPerm(): 7777

$ stat --printf "Permissions: %a\n" example_file
Permissions: 7777
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need to use golang to get the file permissions of a given file (specifically the SUID bit)

Ok, add this: `fmt.Printf("File has SUID bit set: %t\n", info.Mode()&os.ModeSetuid != 0)`

> The golang results are inconsistant because ugtrwxrwxrwx != 0777

`info.Mode()` and `info.Mode().Perm()` are different things, though related.

`info.Mode().Perm()` contains a subset of `info.Mode()`. `info.Mode().Perm()` is simply a little convenience function to do a bit-wise AND with a constant mask `0777`.

> Is this a limitation of go?

No